# How to improve image alignment with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I have a project where people can add data about utility bills, and there's also an OCR service inside. So people from my city can recognize data from bills just by loading their photos of bills. The trouble is that I can't reach this goal fully.

So I have 4 templates of bills (like for heating, water, gas and so on) in high quality. Example is below: [image]

My user can load a picture like that:
[image]

And after alignment I get this result:
[image]

And it's obvious that I can't get good recognition with such image.
My code which I use for image alignment:

```
import os

import cv2
import numpy as np

from config import folder_path_aligned_images

MAX_FEATURES = 500
GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.15


class OpenCV:
    @classmethod
    def match_img(cls, im1, im2):
        # Convert images to grayscale
        im1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        im2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.
        orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_FEATURES)
        keypoints_1, descriptors_1 = orb.detectAndCompute(im1_gray, None)
        keypoints_2, descriptors_2 = orb.detectAndCompute(im2_gray, None)

        # Match features.
        matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
        matches = matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, None)

        # Sort matches by score
        matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)

        # Remove not so good matches
        num_good_matches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
        matches = matches[:num_good_matches]

        # Draw top matches
        im_matches = cv2.drawMatches(im1, keypoints_1, im2, keypoints_2, matches, None)
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(folder_path_aligned_images, "matches.jpg"), im_matches)

        # Extract location of good matches
        points_1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
        points_2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

        for i, match in enumerate(matches):
            points_1[i, :] = keypoints_1[match.queryIdx].pt
            points_2[i, :] = keypoints_2[match.trainIdx].pt

        # Find homography
        h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points_1, points_2, cv2.RANSAC)

        # Use homography
        height, width, channels = im2.shape
        im1_reg = cv2.warpPerspective(im1, h, (width, height))

        return im1_reg, h

    @classmethod
    def align_img(cls, template_path, raw_img_path, result_img_path):
        # Read reference image
        ref_filename = template_path
        print("Reading reference image: ", ref_filename)
        im_reference = cv2.imread(ref_filename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        # Read image to be aligned
        im_filename = raw_img_path
        print("Reading image to align: ", im_filename)
        im = cv2.imread(raw_img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        print("Aligning images ...")
        # Registered image will be resorted in im_reg.
        im_reg, h = OpenCV.match_img(im, im_reference)

        # Write aligned image to disk.
        print("Saving aligned image : ", result_img_path)
        cv2.imwrite(result_img_path, im_reg)

        return result_img_path
```

How can I improve this?

**EDIT:** image with matches:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the detected feature points in both images ?

Comment: Note that matching feature points might not be the best idea, as the image contains innumerable similar features. On another hand, finding the outline (on a contrasted background) is easy.

Comment: I attached the image with matches. So @YvesDaoust you think that there is a better way to align such kind of content?

Comment: "Better" is the superlative of "good", but I see that the computed homography is just very poor. I already gave a hint.

Comment: I would use SIFT (SIFT patent expired recently) and the Lowe ratio distance to filter the matches. Another approach if the background is always this table (an uniform background with a color different from the paper) would be to detect, extract the sheet of paper.

Comment: Try following: 
1. Since the bills are white, use this to find a contour of the bill through thresholding.
2. Create an oriented bounding box of this contour. 
3. Take these four corners and compute homography with the template and warp your image. (assuming that the user will take an image in a roughly upright position).
This will give you a pretty nice bill cutout to work with. From here, you can run your OCR pipeline.
(In answer from @Artem, I tried with Max_Features: 50000 and GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT: 0.01, it gives a relatively better result but it is still not a normal plane to viewer.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this helps almost a year on, but I used a similar code that you have, and what worked for me was to increase the number of MAX_FEATURES (I use 80000, but you might not even need that much) and to **decrease** the GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT to like 0.05. Try playing with the numbers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).